# Create violine plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks, violinplot

I use pgfplots for most of my plots. Now I need to add a [violin plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot). Is this possible with pgfplots or any other package?

Comment: pgfplots can do box plots out of the box. There is no builtin method for violin plots, so one would need to implement it manually.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger is it likely pgfplots will implement it in the future?

Comment: It believe that is unlikely for now: there are items of higher priority and I have to find time to implement them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is (likely) a feature request.

Comment: There's a bug for that: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/378

Comment: As for closing the question, one might as well mention that a solution now exists with the [tikzviolinplots](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzviolinplots) package.