# How to plot violin plot from a box plot in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, violinplot

I have a box plot using tikz in LaTeX, as in the following:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
     \begin{axis}
       [width=\linewidth, height=4cm,
       ytick={1,2},
       yticklabels={A, B},
       xlabel=A, or B
       ] coordinates {};
       \addplot+[fill, draw=black,
       boxplot] 
       table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\ 
        2\\2\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\1\\2\\0\\0\\0\\2\\
        };
       \addplot+[fill, draw=black,
       boxplot] 
       table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1\\5\\15\\15\\3\\3\\2\\5\\4\\1\\14\\2\\4\\1\\0\\2\\ 
        };
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to draw the violin plot for the same data and how in LaTeX?
Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Probably interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192162/134144

Comment: @leandriis , I see, thank you for the info and sharing the link!

Comment: Suggestion: A R plot using  `knitr` with  `tikzDevice`   if you need use the same fonts of LaTeX document. Of course, R can do violin plots.

Comment: @Fran, Thank you so much. Yes, now I'm using R to make violin plots.